# Touch not detected while scrolling (UITableview) while animating cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have added an animation for cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row > lastIndexPath.row{
        cell.animate(up: lastIndexPath.row < indexPath.row ? true : false)
        lastIndexPath = indexPath
    }
}
```

Animate function:

```
 func animate(up:Bool)  {
    self.alpha = 0
    let transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, 0, up ? 200 : -200 , 0)
    self.layer.transform = transform

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.05, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.alpha = 1
        self.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    })
}
```

The height of the cell is 200.

This animation works perfectly, but the problem is while scrolling, touches are not detected until the animation is finished.

i.e. if I scroll up and after that I want to stop that scrolling, but due to that animation I can't stop the scrolling at the desired cell.

Comment: when Lastindexpath.row < indexpath.row  will true ? because indexpath.row will always less than lastindexpath.row.

Comment: I suggest you to change condition to  ( indexpath.row < lastindexpath.row ).

Comment: @Sagarkoyani- not always. while scrolling upside its not less then